# How can I know that my process is being killed in c#?

Tags: c#, windows, service, process, terminate

How can I know that my process is being killed?

For example, if someone wants to kill my Windows service, I can stop it.

Is there a function or sample code?
Or even a library?

Like what antivirus services do. Please look at this link ...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N0YisU6Kfd4&t=11s

This is an example of my code but not what I want...

Please explain clearly?

In the meantime, I've already searched enough

Please give a quick overview

```
public static class Unkillable
{
     [DllImport("ntdll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
     private static extern void RtlSetProcessIsCritical(UInt32 v1, UInt32 v2, UInt32 v3);

     public static void MakeProcessUnkillable()
     {
         Process.EnterDebugMode();
         RtlSetProcessIsCritical(1, 0, 0);
     }

     public static void MakeProcessKillable()
     {
         RtlSetProcessIsCritical(0, 0, 0);
     }
}
```

Comment: If you want to be "like Antivirus services" then go ahead - [Microsoft Virus Initiative](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/intelligence/virus-initiative-criteria). Note that there are quite a few hoops to jump through.

Comment: What is your ask exactly "How can I detect when my process is killed" or "How can I prevent anyone from killing my process" ?